# Trying to fetch YouTube video title and description

Tags: php, json, video, youtube, youtube-api

I want to fetch a YouTube video title and description by its Video ID. Here is what I've tried:

```
$videoid = 'UW7Uzqh8EnE';
$apikey = '***************Got From youtube data api*****************';

$json = file_get_contents('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id='.$videoid.'&key='.$apikey.'&part=snippet
$ytdata = json_decode($json);
echo '<h1>Title: ' . $ytdata->items[0]->snippet->title . '</h1>';
echo 'Description: ' . $ytdata->items[0]->snippet->description;
```

But the above code gives this error:

> PHP Warning:
> file_get_contents(https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=byp94CCWKSI&key=************amp;part=snippet,contentDetails,statistics,status):
> failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden
>
> PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in

I am still receiving the *same* error.

Comment: If you have generated new key it takes upto 8 hours to activate then only you can get the response from youtube api

Comment: @Norman that key wasn't real one

Comment: @Apoorv seriously Not. keys are generated instantly and work as soon as you create them.    sagar check out the Google php client library it will make your life easer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### 1. For the video title

```
    echo video_title('VIDEO_ID');

    function video_title($id)
    { 
        $content = file_get_contents("http://youtube.com/get_video_info?video_id=" . $id);
        parse_str($content, $output);
        return $output['title'];
    }
```

#### 2. For the video description

```
    echo video_description('VIDEO_ID');

    function video_description($id)
    { 
        $content = file_get_contents("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&id=" . $id . "&key=YOUR_API_KEY");
        $output = json_decode($content, true);
        return $output['items']['0']['snippet'];
    }
```

Comment: There's no explanation as to why `file_get_contents` works here and not in the original post. I have the same problem, but what is the solution?